# Sharelatex does not recompile anymore

Tags: compiling

My sharelatex project suddenly stopped working. Every time I try to recompile it, it takes very long and then it displays the following message:

*"Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a large number of high-res images, or complicated diagrams."*

What's also weird is that all the warnings are dissappeared now as well? When I check my logs and output file it says: *" No errors, good job"*.

Can someone please let me know how I can get it to compile again, I am kind of in a hurry as my thesis deadline is approaching :(.

Thank you!

Comment: how can we debug given no information. Perhaps you have coded an infinite loop such as `\def\x{\x}  \x` so every job takes forever until the system stops it with a timeout.

Comment: Looking into a magic chrystal ball the answer is: Provide the code ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to all of this. Do you mean copy pasting everything in here, I have a lot of text and tables etc, so It's a lot of text really?

Comment: @Lana no you should not need to post more than a few lines. make a _copy_ of your document  project in sharepoint. Does the problem still occur (if not, you are done) if so delete the second half, does the problem go away, if so put the second half back and delete the first half, repeat until you get a small enough document that you can post

Comment: @lana If you have saved the last version of your code that compiled successfully, go back to that and scrutinize every step you have taken since and find out what change made the thing blow up. A big if! If not, use the method David Carlisle suggests for producing a `Minimal Working Example (MWE)`. ... and I just notice my suggestion is a duplicate too, staenne said it all 11 minutes ago.

Comment: It worked ! I copied it and the copy does compile but the old version does not quite weird as they are still similar! I guess Ill just continue working in the copied version. Thanx a lot for your help guys!

Comment: It sometimes happens that older auxiliary files (aux-file, toc-file etc) are faulty and prevent a successfull compilation. In sharelatex there is a button to delete all such auxiliary files to start a clean compilation.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do when faced with a time out problem such as this is to clear the cache on the project. This can be done by clicking the trash can icon at the bottom of the error logs window. If this does not work, then try some of the steps outlined [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Debugging_Compilation_timeout_errors/).Timeout errors such as these are usually caused by some mistake in the LaTeX code, such as a missing bracket, or a blank line in a \title{...} or \author{...} statement.

If you could make an example of the project public and post a link to it here, then we would be able to provide more insight as to the problem.

Comment: Your link gives me "Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for."

Answer (score 2):

I had struggled with this issue for a day and concluded the following:

a) If you code has error than this issue is genuine. You can look for ways to fix this over here:
  1) https://www.overleaf.com/help/46-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-compile-timeout-error-message#.Wv39T0gvyHs
  2) https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Debugging_Compilation_timeout_errors

b) However, most of the time your code would be correct but you still get this error due to severely limited capabilities of Sharelatex and Overleaf.

My conclusion is, if you are working on a complex document which involves high-resolution images you are better off working offline using Latex IDE like Kile or TexMaker.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Recent Changes" button in the top left (clock with counter clockwise arrow) and go back to when you last could compile. And start again from there.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the reasons concerning the solutions given above, another reason for the error regarding compilation 'time-out' may be because your data connection is very slow (maybe temporarily though). I totally agree with the solutions given by experts. In addition, the solution(s) I would like to provide here are:

1. Clear the cache data of the browser and the compiler
2. Run the browser on DNS settings > Cloudflare. It may sometimes give you a better experience regarding the speed, and the better the speed, the lesser the compilation time (because the file needs to be compiled within 4 minutes in the free versions of most Latex editing platforms).
3. Try using a different compiler e.g., if you're using 'LuaLatex' try 'XeLatex' and vice-versa (If a particular compiler is not necessarily required based on the dependencies)
4. Use codes for tables and diagrams rather than using high-resolution images

Thank you! Wish you all the best!